# How can I make an array of lines grow or shrink depending on a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

[image]
So I'm trying to model a gate, and although I found a way to make the pickets (iron tubes) be spaced from each other at the same length, I can't find a way to make them scale/ resize along the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a lattice modifier. You can additionally use a Vertex Group and only assign the top vertices on each post so you don't affect anything except the height of the row. Push `O` (the letter, not zero) to turn on proportional editing mode and you can edit the lattice super smoothly.

[image]

The default "Smooth" editing mode should work but it comes with a buttload of settings to experiment with.

[image]

To add a Lattice Mod, add a Lattice object and scale it in Object Mode to fit your object.

[image]

Then in the details panel edit the UVW settings to give it more segments.

Think of U, V, W as X, Y, Z. They're the same thing.

[image]

Don't put too many, if you do alot then it kind of defeats the purpose of the lattice mod and will make it messy. I may have even put to much here but whatever.

[image]

Then just select your object, then the lattice, then push `Ctrl+P` and select "Lattice Deform" to quick-add a lattice modifier.

[image]

Then you can add a Vertex group to only affect certain parts of your mesh like by selecting them and clicking assign in the object data panel.

[image]

Then in the modifier panel add that Group to the modifier.

[image]

Then you can go to town.